# Check if first character is a number - Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, discord, discord.js

Working on a 'Remind Me' command, and `arg[0]` is where you input the time, using the ms node module.

An example of the command would be `-remindme 5s test`
I need to check if the first character (in the example it would be `5`)

Initially, I tried:

```
if(isNaN(args[0])) {
   return message.channel.send('Your first input must be how long you wish the reminder to be!')
 }
```

Which in my example would be `5s`, but I only need to check the first character.

I have been told to use `regex` but I have never touched that and have no idea how it works.

Comment: `if (/^\d/.test(args[0])) { /* ... */ }` _(`^` is the start of the string, `\d` is a digit)_

Comment: Your problem is that you are asking if `"5"` is not a number. Well... it is a string! But if you would ask if `+"5"` is a number, it would convert the string to a number and if the character is not a valid number, it would be cast to `NaN`.

Comment: @Akxe IsNaN will interpret numerical strings as a number and return false if they contain only numbers.

Comment: Blex, that worked, thank you. I can't mark it as an answer as it's a comment though.

Answer (score 1):

Using the package ms you can just use:

```js
if (args[0] && ms(args[0]) == undefined) {
   message.channel.send("Input a valid time 12d/12h/12m/12s")
}
```

`ms` just return undefined when a invalid time is setted in the parameter.

`Hope it helps!`

Comment: Better than a lot of check if is number or not :D